# How i can divide test train data for churn prediction?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I have telecom 7 months data, the definition of churn for telecom is "Customer who does not pay monthly bill consecutive 3 months is the churn" now i have to predict who will be churn in future. So, my question is how i can divide my data into train test to get better result? I did some work like i drop one month then divide the data into two parts 3 months each , i made flag from test and attach with train but the results are not good. can you help me out?

Comment: Is it imbalanced data? what is the percentage of churn customers in your data?

Comment: 25% are churn customers i made flag from test data those who didnt pay bill in (oct ,nov ,dec) and attached with training data (jul ,aug ,sep).